# Reverted transaction from quote?

Tags: 0x

Im receiving quotes from the 0x API (with IntentOnFilling and takerAddress specified). Can someone help me with debugging this transaction that was reverted by the exchangeProxy.

Quote request was:

```
api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=USDC&sellToken=DAI&sellAmount=16541368192782056804708&slippagePercentage=0.005&takerAddress=0x1BcBD397ee58276704245F0F30Ff0d34D178b955&intentOnFilling=true
```

Transaction reverted

> https://etherscan.io/tx/0x38addfd059504617ac7b6863d46b0af8f4d5639fac2a30fb6b3c31ffcb94abf0/advanced

What should I change? I already defined the GasLimit to be 20% above the estimate so that cannot be the reason (also would be another error code).

Any ideas!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimum output token amount was defined according to the value of the `slippagePercentage` sent with your API request.

The total amount of USDC that would have been transferred to the taker address was `16468700990.0`, which is less than `minOutputTokenAmount=17107272976`, [causing the transaction to revert](https://ethtx.info/mainnet/0x38addfd059504617ac7b6863d46b0af8f4d5639fac2a30fb6b3c31ffcb94abf0/).

This is probably due to price changes within the source of the swap.